# Word list for use in commercial game

Tags: game-mechanics

I need a word list to use in a commercial game (even though the game will be free to download)

Something like this

http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/ospd.txt

Would be perfect (needs to be formatted .txt file) but obviously allowed to be used in a commercial game. I'm happy to pay if it's not too much.

Thanks for any advice.

*UPDATE*

After some more research (google), I came across this passage. Thought this might be useful for other people, although it still seems in contradiction to what the replies are saying on stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277703/license-of-popular-dictionary-word-lists-e-g-sowpods-twl-copyright-tradema)

"The nearest thing to a licence text for ENABLE, of which ABLE forms a part, is as follows.

The ENABLE master word list, WORD.LST, is herewith formally released
into the Public Domain. Anyone is free to use it or distribute it in
any manner they see fit. No fee or registration is required for its
use nor are "contributions" solicited (if you feel you absolutely
must contribute something for your own peace of mind, the authors of
the ENABLE list ask that you make a donation on their behalf to your
favorite charity). This word list is our gift to the Scrabble community,
as an alternate to "official" word lists. Game designers may feel free
to incorporate the WORD.LST into their games. Please mention the source
and credit us as originators of the list. Note that if you, as a game
designer, use the WORD.LST in your product, you may still copyright and
protect your product, but you may *not* legally copyright or in any way
restrict redistribution of the WORD.LST portion of your product. This
*may* under law restrict your rights to restrict your users' rights,
but that is only fair.

M Cooper and Alan Beale
"

From this site
http://www.quinapalus.com/dicts.html

Obviously I have no way of knowing if that's legit or not, so I was wondering what other peoples advice still is.

Comment: Not really the place for this question... And what's wrong with the one you linked?

Comment: I thought if it was related to game development it would be ok. That's the scrabble word list and is copywritten.

Comment: Yep, it's related to game development. But it's not really different than asking where to [find free or cheap assets](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/669/where-can-i-find-art-resources-questions-off-topic-not-a-real-question/), which is a type of question that's defined as outside the scope for this site. See the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) about that. It ends up just generating a list, which isn't the goal of this site.

Comment: FWIW, incidentally, I've heard people making alarmist claims about using the Scrabble wordlists but as far as I know (and with the IANAL disclaimer) you should be in the clear to use them; mere lists of data are not copyrightable, at least in the US, and this has been affirmed by repeated court cases.

Comment: The replies here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277703/license-of-popular-dictionary-word-lists-e-g-sowpods-twl-copyright-tradema
seem to suggest that the list is copywritten?

Comment: @Phil: That's An Interesting Question. The replies clearly imply that Hasbro _claims_ the list is copywritten - which is a legitimate concern, since the mere threat will be enough for many companies - but AFAICT they've never successfully enforced *that* claim (as opposed to their trademark claims) in any court case; I'd love to see an explicit judgement to that effect.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about where to find resources, not game development.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the site you linked your list from:

> The official Scrabble player's dictionary, known as OSPD, is widely available on the internet. There is also a list targetted at Scrabble players known as the Enable list. This has been explicitly placed in the public domain.

In addition, [the page](http://www.puzzlers.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=solving:wordlists:about:start) the link resides on contains numerous other lists of words that are free to use.

**EDIT**

You found in your update, what I'd already said in my answer. Additionally, the SE link you've posted has plenty of alternative answers. For example: [The English Open Word List](http://diginoodles.com/The_English_Open_Word_List_%28EOWL%29), has more words that the OSPD and it's restriction free. Beyond that, the Enable list, as I said in my answer, seems to be a very good choice and is in the public domain.

Comment: The replies here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277703/license-of-popular-dictionary-word-lists-e-g-sowpods-twl-copyright-tradema
Seem to suggest that the scrabble list is copywritten.

Answer (score -1):

I generally don't think you have to "pay" to use a word list.

Any word list you find can easily be reformatted using a bit of string manipulation / text output.

For a large group of word lists, [just go here](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I actually tried downloading one of those when I was looking for an answer myself. I didn't look too deeply, but they appeared to be programs that generate word lists formatted specifically for things like spell checking or converting between American English and British English. Possibly a good fit for what the OP is looking for, but I'm not so sure.

Comment: I had a look at those files, but couldn't see any explanation on how to use them/get words from them. All I need is just a .txt file like I originally linked too.